# Conditional entropy as relative entropy between probability distributions

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang, entropy, relative-entropy

> Find the expression for the conditional entropy $H(Y|X)$ as a relative entropy between two probability distributions.  Use this expression to deduce that $H(Y |X)≥0$, and to find the equality conditions.

This is given in [Exercise 11.7, Page 507-508, Chapter 8, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielsen and Chuang](http://mmrc.amss.cas.cn/tlb/201702/W020170224608149940643.pdf)

The relative entropy of two probability distributions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ is defined as, $H(p(x)||q(x))=\sum_xp(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, where the probability distributions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ must be defined over the same set.

The mutual information $H(X:Y)$ can be expressed as the relative entropy of two probability distributions, as
\begin{align}
H(X:Y)&=H(X)+H(Y)-H(X,Y)\\
&=-\sum_xp(x)\log p(x)-\sum_y p(y)\log p(y)+\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log p(x,y)\\
\text{Since we have }& p(x)=\sum_yp(x,y)\text{ and }p(y)=\sum_xp(x,y)\\
H(X:Y)&=\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)p(y)}=H(p(x,y)||p(x)p(y))
\end{align}

**My Attempt**

The conditional entropy $H(Y|X)$ between two probability distributions is defined as,
$$
H(Y|X)=\sum_x p(x)H(Y|X=x)=\sum_xp(x).-\sum_yp(y|x)\log p(y|x)\\
=-\sum_{x,y}p(x)p(y|x)\log p(y|x)=-\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log p(y|x)\\
\text{Since we have } p(y|x)=\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}\\
H(Y|X)=-\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log \frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)\log \frac{p(x)}{p(x,y)}\\
=\sum_{x}\sum_{y}p(x,y)\log \frac{p(x)}{p(x,y)}
$$

Can I proceed further to obtain that the conditional entropy $H(Y|X)$ as a relative entropy between two probability distributions ?

---

Or can I write as,
$$
H(X:Y)=H(p(x,y)||p(x)p(y))=H(Y)-H(Y|X)\\
\implies H(Y|X)=H(Y)-H(X:Y)=H(Y)-H(p(x,y)||p(x)p(y))
$$

Comment: what's the required form exactly? Isn't the last expression you write already written in terms of a relative entropy, as it's $H(p \| p_X\otimes I)$ (I'm not sure what notation you use for this; I just mean with $p_X\otimes I$ the function $(x,y)\mapsto p_X(x)$ with $p_X(x)\equiv\sum_y p(x,y)$ the marginal distribution)?

Comment: Its just that the second distribution is not normalised. If you want to normalise it then you have to subtract something from the conditional entropy.

Comment: @glS The question is "find an expression for the conditional entropy $H(Y |X)$ as a relative entropy between two probability distributions". So is it $H(Y|X)=-\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)\log\frac{p(x,y)}{(p_X\otimes I)(x,y)}=-H(p(x,y)||(p_X\otimes I)(x,y))$, where $(p_X\otimes I)(x,y)=p(x)$ ?

Comment: @Rammus you mean then to obtain $H(Y|X)=H(Y)-H(p(x,y)||p(x)p(y))$ ?

Comment: No, that's not correct, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative entropy is defined as
$$
D(p\|q) = \sum_x p(x) \log\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right).
$$
The conditional entropy of $Y$ given $X$ for two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is defined as
$$
H(Y|X) = -\sum_{xy} p(x,y) \log(p(y|x))\,.
$$

Now consider a distribution $p$ which is the joint distribution for two random variables $X$ and $Y$. And consider also a distribution $q$ which is defined as $q(x,y) := \frac{p(x)}{d_Y}$ where $d_Y$ is the number of outcomes for the random variable Y. Effectively $q$ is a product distribution of the marginal distribution of $X$ together with a uniform distribution over the outcome space of $Y$. Crucially $q$ is a normalized distribution which is what the question seems to be asking for. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
-D(p\|q) &= -\sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \log \left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)/d_Y}\right) \\
&= -\sum_{x,y} p(x,y) \left(\log\left(\frac{p(x,y)}{p(x)}\right) + \log(d_Y)\right) \\
&= -\sum_{x,y}p(x,y) \log(p(y|x)) - \sum_{x,y}p(x,y) \log(d_Y) \\
&= H(Y|X) - \log(d_Y)
\end{aligned}
$$
So overall
$$
H(Y|X) = -D(p(x,y) \| p(x)/d_Y) + \log(d_Y)\,.
$$